# Thunderbird 78: Hide an IMAP Folder

Tags: email, sync, thunderbird, imap

I checked the documentation for [IMAP Synchronization](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization). But I am hoping to hide a particular folder from an email completely. For example, in an email abc@outlook.de, I have a folder inside it called xyz. I want to see all folders of abc@outlook.de in my Thunderbird and hide the folder xyz as if it doesn't exists.

Any suggestions if this is possible on Thunderbird  78.

Comment: On IMAP you can subscribe each folder or not. I have not checked the recent version of TB but in older versions I know that you could subscribe or unsubscribe each folder individually.

Comment: I read this, which is also given on the website that I mentioned in the question. Subscribe or unsubscribe doesn't hide the folder.

Comment: If you remove the checkmark from a folder in the subscribe dialog the folder is no longer visible in TB. Just tested in the latest TB version.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Did you remove the checkmark here: Edit -> Account Settings -> Synchronization and Storage -> Advanced -> Items for offline Use? Or did you do somewhere else. Please  tell me (because this doesn't work for me).

Comment: No, I am referring to the subscribe dialog that can be opened using the context menu of the root element of each mail account in the tree view. https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-subscribe-to-imap-folders-in-thunderbird/

Answer (score 4):

I know it is a bit old discussion.
Nowadays I have TB v102.13.
I had the same problem. Fixed it with a single check mark:
account settings-> server settings -> pressing the "advanced" button ->
checked the "show only subscribed folders".
Hope this will help